# Error getting android attriblute value in customview [from style]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-theme

I am creating CustomView for textview or button to change to **custom font** [bold / normal].

for getting `android:textStyle` in my customview , I am using following code.

```
int textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textStyle", 0);

switch (textStyle) {
    case 1: // bold
        // settypeface with Bold font


    case 0: // regular
    default:
        // settypeface with normal font
}
```

when i use following markup , it works good [gives bold version of font].

```
<com.customfont.CustomFontButton
                     .
                     .  
                     . 
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

But when I try it by using style of button , it always gives default value of `textStyle` variable which is 0. And results in normal version of font.

```
<com.customfont.CustomFontButton
   .
   .
   .
   style="@style/ButtonStyle"
/>
```

My style for this button is

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_bg</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item> -->

    </style>
```

as seen , it has `textStyle` set to `bold`. But this button is not getting bold as it should. And one more thing , my theme is applying correctly in menifest.

So what can be done with having `textStyle` in styles.xml for not setting manually for each button in app ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: just replace _pareny_ to _parent_ in style.

Comment: try to comment _android:textAppearance_ property of style.

Comment: still no luck. :( , for now , I have `android:textStyle="bold" ` in all buttons in app . Thnq for your help. Hope I have a solution for it.